# SVM for data prediction in R

Tags: r, svm, forecast

I'd like to use the 'e1071' library for fitting an SVM model. So far, I've made a model that creates a curve regression based on the data set.
(take a look at the purple curve):

[image: SVMs curve]

However, I want the SVM model to "follow" the data, such that the prediction for each value is as close as possible to the actual data. I think this is possible because of this graph that shows how SVMs (model 2) model are similar to an ARIMA model (model 1):

[image: ARIMA + svm]

I tried changing the kernel to no avail. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Fine tuning a SVM classifier is no easy task. Have you considered other models? For ex. GAM's (generalized additive models)? These work well on very curvy data.

Comment: I will try it out, thanks. But I am wondering how to construct the SVM model for the 2nd graph that I uploaded, as it doesn't look like it is a curve.